# How do I keep this picture gallery in proportion with the screen size?

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

As you can see on [this webpage](http://chelseachendesigns.com/collections.html) the *picture gallery* which I created using JQuery stays in the same position when you enlarge the screen. It works fine on my screen size but in larger screen sizes it doesn't move.

---

so after i fixed my code my previous and next arrows doesn't show up. could someone pls look at the code? thank you!!!
html

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="container">
      <div class="controller" id="prev"></div>
      <div id="slider">
       <img src="ps mock ups/collections/SS1.jpg" width="990" height="554"     alt=""/> 
       <img src="ps mock ups/collections/SS2" alt="" width="990" height="554"/> 
       <img src="ps mock ups/collections/SS3.jpg" alt="" width="990" height="554"/>
       <img src="ps mock ups/collections/SS4.jpg" alt="" width="990" height="554"/>
       <img src="ps mock ups/collections/SS5.jpg" alt="" width="990" height="554"/>
       <img src="ps mock ups/collections/SS6.jpg" alt="" width="990" height="554"/>
       <img src="ps mock ups/collections/SS7.jpg" alt="" width="990" height="554"/>
       <img src="ps mock ups/collections/SS8" alt="" width="990" height="554"/>
       <img src="ps mock ups/collections/SS9.jpg" alt="" width="990" height="554"/> 
       <img src="ps mock ups/collections/SS10.jpg" alt="" width="990" height="554"/>
       <img src="ps mock ups/collections/SS11" alt="" width="990" height="554"/>
       <img src="ps mock ups/collections/SS12.jpg" alt="" width="990" height="554"/>
       <img src="ps mock ups/collections/SS13" alt="" width="990" height="554"/>
       <img src="ps mock ups/collections/SS14.jpg" alt="" width="990" height="554"/></div>
<div class="controller" id="next"></div>
    </div>
      </div>

#wrap {

    height: 554px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
#prev {
    background-image: url(ps%20mock%20ups/bg/left%20arrow/_.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 554px;
    width: 75px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3%;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background-size: 40% auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
    #next {
    background-image: url(ps%20mock%20ups/bg/left%20arrow/_%20copy.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width: 75px;
    height: 554px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background-size: 40% auto;
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-top: -554px;
}
    #slider {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 990px;
    height: 554px;
}
    #container {
    width: 1190px;
    height: 554px;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: could you create a jsfidlde.http://jsfidlde.net

Comment: Down voted because you only posted link to an external webpage not an jsfiddle or any other way to narrowly see where the problem can be.

Comment: didn't know about the indenting yesterday so didn't know how to add the code.. here it is now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS will fix the slider to center:

```
#wrap {
  height: 554px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#container {
  height: 554px;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

#slider {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 990px;
  height: 554px;
}
```

In your original post you mentioned larger screens so I assume you're referring to screens with resolution higher than `1366x768` therefore, your media query should look like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {

}
```

Inside that query you insert everything you want to run if a screen is wider than 1366 pixels. e.g.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
    #slider {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      width: 1366px;
      height: 554px;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey! thanks so much! it does center the slider, but it still doesnt ajust size according to the scrn size? if you drag the browser horizontally you will see that the size remains same... any insights on that?

Comment: Sure, you need to use CSS media queries to account for scren sizes: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp - Or, you could set the width and the height by `%` instead of `pixels` and see how that works out. In any case, I'd recommend using OwlCarousel which is a pretty awesome plugin for a slider. If this answers your question please accept it and vote up. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! read this and not sure how to do the media queries... can you lay out a basic format for me? sorry.. im a fashion designer and really not even a computer person T_T

Comment: If you're not a computer guy, why are you doing this kind of work sigh. I have revised my answer with a bit of media query code.

Comment: sad for fashion designers who have no graphic designers isn't it.... thanks for the solution! however I think my next and previous arrow have disappeared after i formatted it according to your code? i updated the code from my dreamweaver. pls help me look at those too? T_T

Comment: :) I can see the navigation arrows, you can add `cursor: pointer;` to class `controller` so it looks clickable. Btw, I've seen the about section, great record! There are a few tips I could give you or fix some of your code so it gets better SEO - better results on google. If it comes to that, a small pay might be in order though.

Comment: hey! thanks so much! i think i fixed the arrows tho.. but for some reason they load very slow... if i need that extra tips i will def give you a shout!

Comment: hey odedta! since im so struggling and you are such a pro.. mind to help out on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044433/how-to-keep-a-heading-and-a-set-of-sub-navigations-from-crashing-into-each-other

Comment: really really appreciate this... thank you if you can take a quick look!

Comment: Oh btw, if this answers your question please accept it.