# How to keep a heading and a set of sub-navigations from crashing into each other when decreasing browser size

Tags: html, css, navigation, css-float

as on this webpage http://chelseachendesigns.com/collections.html
when you drag the browser to be smaller horizontally the subnavigations S|S collecitons and F|W collection crashes onto the heading Chelsea Chen. Any solution for this pls? thank you!

```
<div id="wrapper">
<header id="top">
  <h1> &nbsp;C H E L S E A &nbsp; C H E N </h1>
  <nav id="subnav">
    <a href="collections.html" class="ss">S|S Collection</a>
    <a href="FW collection.html">F|W Collection</a>
  </nav>
</header>
</div>


#wrapper #top h1 {
    font-family: poiret-one;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: xx-large;
    position: static;
    display: block;
}
#subnav a {
    width: 40%
%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #686868;
    font-family: gruppo;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: left;
    width: 75%;
    visibility: visible;
    text-decoration: none;
    left: 0px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px;
    clear: none;
    overflow-x: visible;
    margin-left: 22%;
    margin-right: -53%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Comment: What is the desired result? You might want to add HTML,CSS tags to your question so more people can view it.

Comment: hi odedta, the desired result is that when your browser is narrower the sub navigations wont crash onto the CHELSEA CHEN heading.. right now it is doing that...

Comment: basically when you drag the browser window to the left, the sub navigations shouldn't be moving.. if you get what i mean..

Comment: If they don't move your website will not be considered to be responsive and will suffer in google results (mobile) because of it, keep that in mind. If you still want to go through with it, all you need to do is set your navigation bar to a fixed size - in pixels.